# Numpy indexing with multiple clauses

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

When indexing a numpy array, I can select all entries that fit a certain criteria. For example, for multiples of 3:

```
array = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20]])
array[array%3 == 0]
```

Now if I want to select all entries with values multiple of 3 and below 10, I would expect just adding an `and` or `or` to the brackets to be enough. However, I get and error when running the following following code:

```
array = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20]])
array[array%3 == 0 and array<10]
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

What is the correct way of writing such logical clauses when indexing an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `&` operator:

```
>>> array[(array%3 == 0) & (array<10)]
array([3, 6, 9])
```

Don't forget to surround each operand with parentheses, or you will get an error.

Comment: This is the preferred answer

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to do this in two steps.

1. divisible by 3

```
array = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]])
array = array[array%3 == 0]
```

2. less than 10

```
array[array<10]
```

But I am certain there is a way to do this in one line.